# Two sides of a rhombus OABC lying in the first quadrant along the lines $y=x/\sqrt 3$ and $y=x\sqrt 3$. If the area of the rhombus is 2 sq units then

Tags: coordinate-systems

> Prove that length of longer diagonal is $\sqrt 2(\sqrt 3+1)$ and
>
> Length of the side of rhombus is 2 unit

The lines will form an angle of 60 and 30 with the positive x axis

B lies opposite to O (origin) while A lies lower wrt C (hope this clears up the figure I have in mind)

According to the question
$$OB.AC=4$$

Let P be the point of intersection of the diagonals

OB will bisect the angle AOC and will form 45 with the positive x axis

Also angle COP will be 15

Then $\tan 15=\frac{PC}{OP}$
$$\tan 15=\frac{AC}{OB}$$

Putting this in the above equation
$$OB^2=\frac{4}{\tan 15}$$

$$OB=\frac{2}{\sqrt{2-\sqrt 3}}$$

This isn’t matching.
What is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$OB=\frac{2}{\sqrt{2-\sqrt 3}}=\frac{2\sqrt2}{\sqrt{4-2\sqrt 3}}
=\frac{2\sqrt2}{\sqrt{(\sqrt3-1)^2}}
=\frac{2\sqrt2}{\sqrt3-1}=\sqrt2(\sqrt3+1)$$

which does match.

Answer (score 0):

Let OABC be the rhombus with point A on line $y=\sqrt{3} x$ is A$(a , \sqrt{3}a)$ and from symmetry   about y=x other vertex is C$(\sqrt{3}a,a)$ and diagonals are OB : y-x=0 and AC: $x+y=(\sqrt{3}+1)a$.let diagonals intersect at M
$$ $$
Length OM $=\vert \frac{(\sqrt{3}+1)a}{\sqrt{2}} \vert$
$$ $$ length AM $=\vert \frac{(\sqrt{3}-1)}{\sqrt{2}} \vert$
$$ $$
Area of triangle OAM =$\frac{1}{2}(OM)(AM)=1$
$$a^2=2\,\,\,\,\therefore a=\sqrt{2}$$
Hence longest diagonal OB is $a(\sqrt{3}+1)=\sqrt{2}(\sqrt{3}+1)$